# How I can set props in a shallowWrapper?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

How I can set a prop in a childComponent that I get with wrapper.find?

I'm getting this error:

```
ShallowWrapper::setProps() can only be called on the root

  31 | 
> 32 |        gradientComponent.setProps({ onPress:  mockFunction });
     |                       ^
```

And this is the code:

```
describe("<PhoneVerificationScreen> behaviour", () => {
 it("should call onPress", () => {
   const wrapper = setup();
   const gradientComponent = wrapper.find(GradientButton);

   gradientComponent.setProps({ onPress:  mockFunction });
   gradientComponent.simulate('click');

   expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
});
```

Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

In brief: you don't need that.

1. There is no sense in setting props on nested component, in real scenario your ...(whatever component is in `wrapper`) sets props for `GradientButton` child so there is no way to override that.
2. Especially it does not make any sense for `shallow()` since `<GradentButton>` will never be rendered.
3. And finally it seems like you are trying to test React itself by setting event handler for element, then invoking it and verifying if it has been called.